# Error inflating TextView in Android Studio

Tags: android

I get the following error when i try to load my custom list. Previously it worked fine. But now it crashes.
I think it is because i modified the build.gradle files but i cant figure out the solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv455.png)

This is my xml code list_single.xml for CustomList.java

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     >
>
>     <TableRow
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:baselineAligned="false">
>
>         <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 android:layout_width="330dp"
>                 android:layout_height="103dp"
>                 android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
>                 android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
>                 android:background="@drawable/box_attribute_2"
>                 android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
>                 app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
>                 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
>                 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
>                 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
>
>             <ImageButton
>                 android:id="@+id/callbutton"
>                 android:layout_width="36dp"
>                 android:layout_height="33dp"
>                 android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>                 android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
>                 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.971"
>                 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.14999998"
>                 app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call" />
>
>             <ImageButton
>                 android:id="@+id/messagebutton"
>                 android:layout_width="37dp"
>                 android:layout_height="33dp"
>                 android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>                 android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
>                 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.974"
>                 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8"
>                 app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_action_email" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textview_name"
>                 android:layout_width="226dp"
>                 android:layout_height="37dp"
>                 android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>                 android:gravity="center"
>                 android:paddingLeft="3dp"
>                 android:text="TextView"
>                 android:textAlignment="viewStart"
>                 android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
>                 android:textSize="21sp"
>                 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.693"
>                 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textview_address"
>                 android:layout_width="181dp"
>                 android:layout_height="39dp"
>                 android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>                 android:gravity="center"
>                 android:paddingBottom="3dp"
>                 android:paddingLeft="12dp"
>                 android:text="TextView"
>                 android:textAlignment="viewStart"
>                 android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
>                 android:textSize="18sp"
>                 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.658"
>                 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
>                 tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="98dp" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textview_blood"
>                 android:layout_width="28dp"
>                 android:layout_height="39dp"
>                 android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>                 android:gravity="center"
>                 android:paddingBottom="3dp"
>                 android:paddingLeft="3dp"
>                 android:text="T"
>                 android:textAlignment="viewStart"
>                 android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
>                 android:textSize="20sp"
>                 android:textStyle="bold"
>                 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.213"
>                 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
>
>             <ImageView
>                 android:id="@+id/imageview1"
>                 android:layout_width="60dp"
>                 android:layout_height="86dp"
>
>                 android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>                 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
>                 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textview_number"
>                 android:layout_width="198dp"
>                 android:layout_height="31dp"
>                 android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
>                 android:paddingLeft="3dp"
>                 android:paddingTop="7dp"
>                 android:text="TextView"
>                 android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
>                 android:textSize="18sp"
>                 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.525"
>                 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.446" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/textview_blood2"
>                 android:layout_width="80dp"
>                 android:layout_height="31dp"
>                 android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
>                 android:layout_marginStart="110dp"
>                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>                 android:gravity="center"
>                 android:paddingBottom="3dp"
>                 android:paddingLeft="3dp"
>                 android:text="15km"
>                 android:textAlignment="viewStart"
>                 android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
>                 android:textSize="20sp"
>                 android:textStyle="bold"
>                 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textview_number"
>                 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textviewmain"
>                 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textview_number"
>                 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textviewmain" />
>
>
>         </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
>
>     </TableRow>
> </TableLayout>
> ```

Customlist.java

> ```
> package org.raktadaan.jiwandaan.fragments.search;
>
> /**
>  * Created by ayush on 8/13/17.
>  */
>
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
> import android.graphics.Bitmap;
> import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
> import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
> import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
> import android.net.Uri;
> import android.os.Build;
> import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
> import android.util.Base64;
> import android.view.LayoutInflater;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.view.ViewGroup;
> import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
> import android.widget.ImageButton;
> import android.widget.ImageView;
> import android.widget.TextView;
>
> import org.raktadaan.jiwandaan.R;
> import org.raktadaan.jiwandaan.fragments.post_message.message_activity;
>
> import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
> import java.math.BigDecimal;
>
> public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
>
>     private final Context context;
>     private final String[] name,location,blood_group,contact,gender,distance,photo;
>     private final Double[] distan=new Double[10000];
>
>     public CustomList(Context context,
>     String[] name, String[] location, String[] blood_group, String[] contact, String[] gender, String[] photo, String[] distance){
>         super(context, R.layout.list_single, name);
>         this.context = context;
>         this.name = name;
>
>         this.location = location;
>         this.blood_group = blood_group;
>         this.contact = contact;
>         this.gender = gender;
>         this.photo=photo;
>         this.distance=distance;
>
>        // this.imageId = imageId;
>
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
>
>         LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
>         final View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
>         ImageButton call, message;
>
>
>         TextView mains, names, locations, bloods,number,dist;
>         ImageView propic;
>
>         call=(ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.callbutton);
>         call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
>         {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v)
>             {
>
>                 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
>                 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+contact[position]));
>                 context.startActivity(callIntent);
>
>
>             }
>         });
>
>         message = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.messagebutton);
>
>
>
>         message.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>
>                 Intent i = new Intent(context,message_activity.class);
>                 i.putExtra("e1_name",name[position]);
>                 i.putExtra("e2_number",contact[position]);
>                 i.putExtra("e3_location",location[position]);
>                 i.putExtra("e4_blood",blood_group[position]);
>                 context.startActivity(i);
>             }
>         });
>
>         mains = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textviewmain);
>         propic= (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
>         /*names= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textview_name);
>         locations= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textview_address);
>         bloods= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textview_blood);
>
>         number= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textview_number);
>         dist= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textview_blood2);
> //        Log.e("name",name[position]);
>         names.setText(name[position]);
>         locations.setText(location[position]);
>         bloods.setText(blood_group[position]);
>         number.setText(contact[position]);
>         distan[position]= Double.parseDouble(distance[position]);
>         distance[position]= String.format("%.1f", new BigDecimal(distan[position]));
>         dist.setText(distance[position]+"km");*/
>
>
>         byte[] images= Base64.decode(photo[position],0);
>         Bitmap picture= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(images,0,images.length);
>
>         ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>         picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,1/100,byteArrayOutputStream);
>
>         Drawable dp=new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),picture);
>
>
>        /* if(gender[position]!=null && gender[position].equals("Others"))
>             propic.setImageResource(imageId[2]);
>         else if(gender[position]!=null && gender[position].equals("Female"))
>             propic.setImageResource(imageId[1]);
>         else*/
>             propic.setImageDrawable(dp);
>
>
>
>         return rowView;
>     }
>     public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
>         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
>             for (String permission : permissions) {
>                 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>                     return false;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         return true;
>     }
> }
> ```

PLease help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is

> Error inflating TextView

So we check `TextView` first .

In your code .You just use `mains = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textviewmain);` .

So you can check **`android:background="@drawable/box_attribute_2"`** in your xml code .

And check `box_attribute_2` .

Also you can use `android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"` to try .

Comment: Thanks you so much. The problem was with @drawable/box_attribute_2. It works now.

Comment: Good luck to you.@AyushKumarShah

Answer (score 0):

You should use the below code in the `getView()` method

```
final View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, false);
```

You should use `false` for the third argument instead of `true`.

Visit [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)) for more detail of the [inflate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)) method

Answer (score -1):

fix TextView in Design part so that you can rectify the error

Comment: fix all the four sides

Comment: Hi there. It would often help to elaborate your solution. A small snippet of code can make it easy for people to understand.